# Incorrect rendering of Gantt chart after data filtering in Angular7

Tags: angular, highcharts, gantt-chart

I work with data visualization on related diseases and targets. I have an array of associated data that is filtered to display in the Gantt Chart depending on the options selected. I got a problem when some of the data is not displayed.

[image]
First scenario:

1. Select Neuroblastoma disease and get the two associated targets.
2. Select the MET target and get only one associated disease. (Problem! Need to two - ALK is not displayed).

Second scenario:

1. Select the MET target and get the two associated diseases.
2. Select the Neuroblastoma disease and get only one associated target (Problem! Need to two - MET is not displayed).

I have prepared a demo for review: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-k4xio

I will be glad if you help me to solve this problem!

UPDATE:

As a temporary workaround, you can change the IDs of the records if they were in the previous set.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code or are you looking for someone to do the debugging for you? Please check the code and let us know which part of it is problematic.

Comment: I tried changing and debugging the code. The problem is that the data in the series is present, but not displayed in the graph.

Comment: This problem occurs (but not always) when loading data into a series if the previous series including the same id or same start/end (if the id not present is data).

Comment: HighCharts developers are confirmed that this is a bug. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12545